# Error al insertar en tabla con composite_primary_keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy programando con la version `2.3.5` de ruby, la versión  de `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (5.1.6)` y la gema: `composite_primary_keys (10.0.2)`, y al insertar en una tabla n-n, con sus claves primarias definidas con la gema me da el siguiente error:

> Invalid column name 'nCodLinDatos,nIdVPN,nIdVLan'

Estas 3 columnas son las que componen la clave principal. Se que el problema es que internamente construye mal la primary key, pero hay alguna solución para las versiones que he especificado arriba?

el código que me lanza el error es el siguiente:

```
result = LinDatosVpnVlan.new( ...... ) result.save
```

En mi fichero model tengo definidas las claves primarias de esta manera:

```
self.primary_keys = [:nCodLinDatos, :nIdVPN, :nIdVLan]
```

para definir la clave compuesta por 3 campos tengo la gema composite_primary_keys

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. En este caso probablemente es importante que pongas todo el código relevante para la pregunta, como la definición de las clases por ejemplo.

Comment: ¿cables primarias o claves primarias?  ◔_◔ Sería útil que muestres el código que usas para crear las tablas y para hacer el insert. El mensaje dice que estás escribiendo un nombre de columna inválido.

Comment: @Pikoh si las claves no funcionan, a uno se le cruzan los cables :) Sandra muestra el código,  [editando la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/140497/edit) para que pueda ser revisado.

Comment: el codigo que me está dando el error es este:
result = LinDatosVpnVlan.new(
                ......
              )
              result.save

las tablas no las he creado yo, ya estaban creadas.

Comment: Sandra, el código del `INSERT` es el que deberías mostrar, pues dices que estás teniendo problema al insertar. ¿No tienes ninguna sentencia del tipo `INSERT INTO...`?

Comment: no el insert no lo hago yo, he visto con puntos de interrupción el insert que hace, y el problema es que en el insert pone lo siguiente: 
OUTPUT INSERTED.[nCodLinDatos,nIdVPN,nIdVLan]
por lo tanto lo considera como una única columna, pero en realidad esas 3 son las columnas diferentes que forman la clave principal de mi tabla.

(no se si me explico muy bien... sorry)

Comment: nada, no funciona :(

Comment: si, el mismo, creo que el problema viene de que la gema no es compatible
con el sqlserver-adapter, he leido en este mismo foro pero en ingles que modificando un modulo de sqlserver-adapter se soluciona pero claro en otra versión que no es la mía porque yo  ese modulo no le tengo

Comment: Pues en ese caso, no puedo ayudarte ya que no tengo ni idea de ruby. A ver si hay suerte y alguien puede hacerlo.

Comment: muchas gracias de todas formas Pikoh :)

Comment: ¿Que versión de rails usas? Porque tu versión de la gema sólo funciona con 5.1.x

Comment: versión de rails 5.1.4